# Concatenate sql values to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a SQL Server 2008 I'm trying to get a comma separated list of all selected values into a variable.

```
SELECT field
FROM table
```

returns:

```
+-------+
| field |
+-------+
| foo   |
+-------+
| bar   |
+-------+
```

I'd like to get:
"foo, bar, "

I tried:

```
DECLARE @foo NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @foo = ''

SELECT @foo = @foo + field + ','
FROM TABLE

PRINT @foo
```

Which returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your table contain any NULLs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to change NULLs

```
SELECT @foo = @foo + ISNULL(field + ',', '')
FROM TABLE
```

or remove them

```
SELECT @foo = @foo + field + ','
FROM TABLE
WHERE field IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote again because it is a perfectly fine answer.

Answer (score 4):

That happens if you have even a SINGLE field in the table that is NULL.  In SQL Server, `NULL + <any> = NULL`.  Either omit them

```
SELECT @foo = @foo + field + ','
FROM TABLE
WHERE field is not null
```

Or work around them

```
SELECT @foo = @foo + isnull(field + ',', '')
FROM TABLE
```

You can write the whole thing without the leading SET statement which is more common.  This query below returns "foo,bar" with no trailing comma

```
DECLARE @foo NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @foo = isnull(@foo + ',', '') + field
FROM TABLE
WHERE field is not null

PRINT @foo
```

Comment: I would not recommend using this approach because it is unreliable. More info [Execution Plan and Results of Aggregate Concatenation Queries Depend Upon Expression Location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515) and [nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior)

Comment: It does work 100% reliably in the forms shown, i.e. without an ORDER BY. Without an order by, the variable keeps growing and at the end of processing, it remains as the end result. When ORDER BY comes into play, the query execution is forced to retain a virtual temp dataset with some transient value of `@var` in each row.  After ordering occurs on these "transient rows", some historical version of the `@variable` state gets imprinted as the final value of the assignment.  Moral of the story is - don't use ORDER BY, or use FOR XML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` around `@foo` (when data type is `char`/`varchar`) in the concatenation other it will not give expected results in SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment Lukasz Szozda made on one of the answers here, you should not use your indicated method to aggregate string values in SQL Server, as this is not supported functionality. While this tends to work when no order clause is used (and even if no exception to this tendency has ever been documented), Microsoft does not guarantee that this will work, and there's always a chance it could stop working in the future. SQL is a declarative language; you cannot assume that behaviour that is not explicitly defined as being the correct behaviour for interpreting a given statement will continue working.

Instead, see the examples below, or see this page for a review of valid ways to achieve the same result, and their respective performance: [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Doing it in a valid way, whichever way you end up using, still has the same considerations as in the other answers here. You either need to exclude NULL values from your result set or be explicit about how you want them to be added to the resulting string.

Further, you should probably use some kind of explicit ordering so that this code is deterministic - it can cause all sorts of problems down the line if code like this can produce a different result when running on the same data, which may happen without an explicit ordering specified.

```
--Null values treated as empty strings
SET @Foo =
    STUFF /*Stuff is used to remove the seperator from the start of the string*/
        (   (SELECT N','/*separator*/ + ISNULL(RTRIM(t.Field), '' /*Use an emptry string in the place of NULL values*/) /*Thing to List*/
            FROM TABLE t
            ORDER BY t.SomeUniqueColumn ASC /*Make the query deterministic*/
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)')
        ,1
        ,1 /*Length of separator*/
        ,N'');

--Null values excluded from result
SET @Foo =
    STUFF /*Stuff is used to remove the seperator from the start of the string*/
        (   (SELECT N','/*separator*/ + RTRIM(t.Field) /*Thing to List*/
            FROM TABLE t
            WHERE t.Field IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY t.SomeUniqueColumn ASC /*Make the query deterministic*/
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)')
        ,1
        ,1 /*Length of separator*/
        ,N'');
```