# Combine values that contribute to aggregation in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL2008R2 Express...

Provided I had a row of data that appeared as such...

```
Value   ID  User
10      5   1
11      7   1
22      5   2
 9      9   2
```

And I wanted to run a query as such to determine what the sum of value was by user...

```
SELECT [user], SUM([value])[value] FROM [MyTable] GROUP BY [user]
```

which would yield

```
User   Value
1      32
2      31
```

All is well, but now say I wanted a representation of what values from the [ID] column contributed to that total?

The scenario is that users perform various tasks that have values ultimately to be summed, averaged, etc.... And I wish to know what specific task lead to the total I am seeing. Essentially a DISTINCT list of all the rows compressed into the aggregation, delimited in some way of course so I can distinguish / parse them on another level. end result would look something like this...

```
User   Value   IDs
1      32      5,7
2      31      5,9
```

Is this doable without going RBAR with temporary tables?

Comment: look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings

Comment: Ok, more complicated than I had originally thought, will test your and the solution provided by gotqn as soon as possible and let you guys know, thank you.

Comment: This solution may have worked, however the below was more concise, and solved the issue so I did not fully test past a workable solution. Thank you however for the contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [Value] TINYINT
    ,[ID] TINYINT
    ,[User] TINYINT
)

INSERT @DataSource ([Value], [ID], [User])
VALUES (10,5,1)
      ,(11,7,1)
      ,(22,5,2)
      ,(9,9,2)

SELECT DS.[User]
      ,SUM(DS.[Value])
      ,SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(4)) FROM @DataSource WHERE [User] = DS.[User] FOR XML PATH('')),2,4000)
FROM @DataSource DS
GROUP BY [User]
```

The above is full working example and generally what is new is the following line:

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(4)) FROM @DataSource WHERE [User] = DS.[User] FOR XML PATH('')),2,4000)
```

It is a ordinary way of concatenating values.

Comment: Ok, more complicated than I had originally thought, will test your and the solution provided by pathfinder as soon as possible and let you guys know, thank you.

Comment: The definitely did exactly what I was looking for, thank you.