# Sum total column

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if my query is correct. I want to group all the dates as one, but my query shows a null.

```
SELECT CustomerID,Cashier, OrderDate,SUM(Total) as totalprice
FROM SalesandReports
GROUP BY CustomerID, Cashier, OrderDate WITH ROLLUP
```

This is the output of my query:

[image: This is the output of my query]

Comment: do your problem solved or not

Answer (score 1):

Try your original query without the WITH ROLLUP on the end - it sounds like you don't actually want rollup, just grouping

Comment: But i want to get the total of all the columns of total price and display it at the buttom

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,Cashier,
    OrderDate,
    SUM(Total) as totalprice
FROM
    SalesandReports
GROUP BY
    OrderDate,
    CustomerID,
    Cashier
WITH ROLLUP
```

By making Orderdate first, the `group by` will be done first according to it and then on customerid and cashier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick here:

```
SELECT
   max(CustomerID) as CustomerId,
   max(Cashier) as Cashier,
   coalsce(OrderDate,'Other Dates'),
   SUM(Total) as totalprice
FROM
   SalesandReports
GROUP BY
   OrderDate WITH ROLLUP
```

By this `GROUP BY`, it will only be done by OrderDate.

Reference: the answers from Stack Overflow question *[Select multiple columns from a table, but group by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217778/select-multiple-columns-from-table-but-group-by-one)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend,

```
SELECT 
CustomerID
,Cashier
, OrderDate
,SUM(ISNULL(totalprice,0)) as totalprice
FROM SalesandReports
WHERE  OrderDate is not NULL  
GROUP BY CustomerID, Cashier, OrderDate
```

Comment: theres no output when i try your query

Comment: change OrderDate != NULL  into  OrderDate is not NULL

Comment: where i can put that?

Comment: Still not total the total price column

Comment: I need to show the sum of totalprice column in the buttom

Comment: No theres no error showing it show correctly but what i need to total the column of total price