# How to use select but allow all fields from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do the following so I am able to group all LineItem's together by count and display the LineItem by count along with the `vendor_name`

```
line_items = LineItem.all
vendor_line_items = line_items.group(:vendor_name).select('COUNT(*) as count', 'vendor_name').order('count desc')
```

My issue is that I am only able to receive the following params: `id: nil, vendor_name: "name_here"`

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing but allow all params from the model to be passed?

Comment: Is your select a mistype (should error)? You are passing 2 arguments when you should only be passing one.

Comment: As is it works, it takes my `LineItem`'s and groups them by `vendor_name` and then sorts them by count.  I can then display them to the front end sorted by count along with which count belongs to which `vendor_name`

Comment: @TheWizard is that what you were referring to or did I miss the ball?

Comment: Yep, all good sorry. I was using a different version of Rails

Answer (score 0):

You can't select the rest of the columns since you have different values for each coulmn inside the group (like... if you have 2 LineItem in the same group, which ID do you expect to have?)

You could apply aggregate functions (like COUNT, MAX, MIN, etc) to other columns on the SELECT to tell the database which columns you want for each column I guess.

Personally, I would first get the groups ordered by count and then do more queries when needed to fetch the actual record for the groups.

```
counts = LineItem.group(:vendor_name).count
# counts should be something like: {vendor_1: X, vendor_2, Y, vendor_3: Z}

# order the vendors using the count for each vendor
ordered_vendors = counts.keys.sort_by { |ven| counts[ven] }

ordered_vendors.each do |vendor|
  # do something with each vendor, fetch LineItems, etc
end
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid doing logic inside the loop

Comment: I guess it depends on what logic you want to do. Or do you mean avoiding the whole loop?

Comment: Well I want a loop to display everything but I was avoiding the looping and getting more records directly on the front end.  If you see my answer down at the bottom of the page, thats what I was aiming to do with group but without needing all of the associations like that (my answer) goes.

Comment: Like is there a way to `LineItem.group(:vendor_name)`-this groups by vendor_name but then instead of it only returning `id: nil, vendor_name: "admin"`, to get more information? Because what I am aiming to get is the sum of another LineItem attribute where `vendor_name` is the in common association.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you only see the count and the vendor name is because that is all you are grouping by. Suppose in the database, you have 5 different Vendor A shown below.

```
vendor_name   | product_name 
-----------------------------
Vendor A      | test        
Vendor A      | test2        
Vendor A      | test3        
Vendor A      | test4 
Vendor A      | test5  
...
```

When you run your query, SQL will not know what to display for product_name as the group_by will only show 1 row instead of 5. [Have a read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217778/select-multiple-columns-from-a-table-but-group-by-one).

To achieve this you will need to either to group by the other columns too or use a min/max select to pick a value to display. Here is an example:

```
vendor_line_items = LineItem.select('COUNT(*) AS count', 'vendor_name', 'MAX(product_name)').group(:vendor_name).order('count DESC')
```

Now each of those results, you can call the `attributes` method.
Which will give you the following hash:

```
vendor_line_items.each do |x|
  result = x.attributes
  # Here result will be a hash.
  # {"count" => 5, "vendor_name" => "Vendor A", "product_name" => "test5"}
end
```

Comment: I trieddoing `vendor_line_items = LineItem.select('COUNT(*) AS count', 'vendor_name', 'SUM(line_item_revenue)').group(:vendor_name).order('count DESC')` but only `vendor_name` and id came up again.  Basically, what I want to display is the LineItem vendor_name, count of those line items and the sum of line_item_revenue, which is the price*quantity

Comment: @uno try giving a name to the sum like `SUM(line_item_revenue) AS summed`

Comment: Do you mean like; `vendor_line_items = LineItem.select('COUNT(*) AS count', 'vendor_name', 'SUM(line_item_revenue) AS summed').group(:vendor_name).order('count DESC')` ? This gave me same results.  There has got to be another way to get more attributes in the results ! ~:)

Comment: Did you try calling .attributes on each of the line items?

Answer (score 0):

(Not accepted answer unless a better way is received)

I did:

```
vendor_line_items = Vendor.joins(:line_items).group(:id).order('COUNT(line_items.id) DESC')
```

This gives me what I want by ordering the results by vendor.line_items.count and allowing me to get all of the associations to display any param I want.

I assume this way is much slower than what I was previously doing as it fetches all records and then on the front end goes through associations to get more records.

In the original way I was doing this.  It is what I want minus an extra parameter that I would want the SUM of.  The parameter is a decimal attribute.  In the same way I count the LineItem that have the same vendor_name, I want to sum of the LineItem.attribute that share the same vendor_name.

Better Answer:

```
LineItem.select(:vendor_name, 'sum(line_item_revenue) as line_item_revenue', 'COUNT(*) as count').group(:vendor_name)
```

This seems to get me what I want with less queries (i believe) --- correct me if I am wrong on the queries.

Answer (score -1):

I am quite confused about your code and your expectation. You are selecting the `COUNT` but the expected result is `id` instead of `count`?

If you want to group by `vendor_name` and show the count of `group_by` you can try

`line_items.group(:vendor_name).count`