# Can I Semicolon Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?

Tags: sql

can i create a sql query that show me only one column but in these column are all the rows with semicolon.
My example:
Select Name from table1 -> Shows

```
[Name]
Peter
Doug
Mustafa
Emre
```

And now i want a query that show me that:

```
[Name]
Peter;Doug;Mustafa;Emre
```

Can u please help me!?

Greetz

Comment: It depends on concrete DBMS you're using.

Comment: I use MS SQL, not MySql!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Comment: They worked with more as one column, but i test it. I think maybe have the same Problem and can give me his query. But Thanks Andy!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #user (username varchar(25))

insert into #user (username) values ('Peter')
insert into #user (username) values ('Doug')
insert into #user (username) values ('Mustafa')
insert into #user (username) values ('Emre')

declare @tmp varchar(250)
SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + username + ';' from #user

select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))
```

modify as you need but it works

Comment: Hi. its looks nice but i dont want to create a table! i found a mysql expression:
Select GROUP_CONCAT(Name ';') Name from Table1
now I need the same for SQL

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the help. Here is my result:

```
SELECT Name = STUFF((
SELECT ';' + Name
FROM Table1
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Greetz