# SQL to join table to aggregate a list of ID?

Tags: sql

Here's the table and what if I want to aggregate the courseID for each student. Can I do that in SQL?

```
StudentCourse
-------------
StudentID  CourseID
1          101
1          102
1          103
2          103
```

What I want:

```
StudentCourse
-------------
StudentID  CourseID
1          101,102,103
2          103
```

Comment: You want this as output of a query, or you want to create a new table that has that format?

Comment: Are you using sql server?

Comment: Loop through each row and build a variable as you loop that contains all the courseids per student - then write that value to a new table and select from there when you are done

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: For Postgres: `select studentid, string_agg(courseid, ',') as courseid from studentcourse group by studentid`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Oracle** database then you can use "**LISTAGG**" function.

```
SELECT StudentID,
    LISTAGG(CourseID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY StudentID) as CourseID
      FROM StudentCourse
        GROUP BY StudentID;
```

Comment: Sorry My mistake.. I edit and mention Oracle database