# Querying single table and merge result for same DateTime

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, merge

I have a table where I insert values, ​​related to an id, that change over time.
Example:

```
| Id  |         Timestamp         |  Value  |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 02:29:31.154  |   7.139 |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 02:40:46.724  |   7.254 |
|  2  |  2018-09-06 02:40:46.724  | 132.451 |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 02:42:19.841  |   7.645 |
|  3  |  2018-09-12 03:01:45.811  |  45.276 |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 03:12:59.121  |   7.421 |
|  2  |  2018-09-12 03:12:59.121  | 130.789 |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 03:15:33.467  |   7.121 |
|  2  |  2018-09-12 03:15:33.467  | 136.198 |
|  3  |  2018-09-12 03:15:33.467  |  46.971 |
|  2  |  2018-09-12 03:27:13.642  | 131.879 |
|  3  |  2018-09-12 03:27:13.642  |  44.645 |
|  1  |  2018-09-12 03:30:27.564  |   7.691 |
| ... |            ...            |   ...   |
```

My goal is to make a single query to take values between a range of dates for `Id` 1, 2 and 3 and marge them together.
The result will be something like this:

```json
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 02:29:31.154", id1: 7.123, id2: null, id3: null }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 02:40:46.724", id1: 7.254, id2: 132.451, id3: null }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 02:42:19.841", id1: 7.645, id2: null, id3: null }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 03:01:45.811", id1: null, id2: null, id3: 45.276 }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 03:12:59.121", id1: 7.421, id2: 130.789, id3: null }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 03:15:33.467", id1: 7.121, id2: 136.198, id3: 46.971 }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 03:27:13.642", id1: null, id2: 131.879, id3: 44.645 }
{ Timestamp: "2018-09-12 03:30:27.564", id1: 7.691, id2: null, id3: null }
```

Is it possible in a single query?

Comment: the `id` is it max at 3 ?

Comment: do you want the result in one long string as what you have shown or in 4 columns ?

Comment: no in my exmaple is max at 3...there are more.

Comment: I need the result in one long string

Comment: @Broge - Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};

var result = (from item in db.Table
              where ids.Contains(item.id) && item.Timestamp > fromDate && item.Timestamp < toDate
              group item by item.Timestamp into sub
              select new 
              {
                  Timestamp = sub.Key,
                  id1 = sub.Where(x => x.id == 1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                  id2 = sub.Where(x => x.id == 2).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                  id3 = sub.Where(x => x.id == 3).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: I never seen this type of query.. Let me know tag of this query.

Comment: I need a query between a range of dates like: `2018-09-12 00:00:00.000` to `2018-09-12 23:59:59.999`

Comment: @Broge, date filter is added

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish - it seems this is "linq"

Comment: Okay.. Thx @SlavaUtesinov.. I will follow this tag.

Answer (score 0):

How about resorting to string aggregation, in SQL Server 2017 using `STRING_AGG()` function [[documentation]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it would work like this:

```
SELECT [Timestamp]
  -- building string very similar to what you've posted; you can certainly play with this column and format it the way you want
  , STRING_AGG(CONCAT('id', CAST(Id AS nvarchar(50)), ': ', ISNULL(CAST([Value] AS nvarchar(50)), N'NULL')), ', ')
FROM schema.Table
GROUP BY [Timestamp];
```

If you're using an older version of SQL Server, logic would be the same, you'd just resort to a custom way of string aggregation, for example one of these:

- [SQL Row concatenation with XML PATH and STUFF](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137045/sql-row-concatenation-with-xml-path-and-stuff-giving-aggregate-sql-error)
- [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

I myself usually use the XML solution when `STRING_AGG()` is not available.

Comment: Just replace `STRING_AGG` with how it's done in the first link and you'll be set.