# SQL concatenate strings in single value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, `users_tbl` and `images` tbl.

Every user can have more than one image.

I'm trying to select all the users and concatenate the user image in a single row

Example :

**Users** tbl

```
user_id    user_name
--------------------
 1          david
 2          tarik
```

**images** tbl

```
image_id   user_id   image_url 
-------------------------------
1            1      "image 12312 url"
2            1      "image 123 url"
3            1      "image 313 url"
4            1      "image 212 url"
5            2      "my image url"
5            2      "my image url2"
```

I need a select statement that returns the following result:

```
user_id   image_url 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     "image 12312 url ,image 123 url,image 313 url,image 212 url"
    2     "my image url , my image url2"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings. Use the XML PATH method pre-SQL 2017 and STRING_AGG in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, you would use `for xml path`:

```
select u.*,
       stuff( (select ', ' + i.image_url
               from images i
               where i.user_id = u.user_id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as image_urls
from users u;
```

EDIT:

If you want the comma at the end, leave out the `stuff()` and use:

```
select u.*,
       (select i.image_url + ', '
        from images i
        where i.user_id = u.user_id
        for xml path ('')
       ) as image_urls
from users u;
```

Comment: how can add a comma at the end of the string too ? like this "my image url , my image url2 ,"

Comment: @TarikHusin . . . `for xml path` returns the results as an XML string, which in this case is the string that you want.