# Returning the distinct records from a table with counts of instances

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database that logs requests made, and I'm trying to find the unique exceptions thrown for each request and the FK that each instance of that exception was thrown by. I've tried a number of different iterations but can't quite seem to find a workable solution so I figured I'd ask here since I'm sure I'm over-thinking this.

Sample data

```sql
Unauthorized User   42
Internal Server Error   57
Unauthorized Employee   88
Bad Request 57
Bad Request 42
Bad Request 42
Bad Request 42
Bad Request 42
Bad Request 42
Unauthorized User   57
```

Sample desired results

```sql
Unauthorized    42, 88, 57
Internal Server Error   57
Bad Request 42, 57
```

EDIT: The version is Sql server 2014 and I changed the data from images to inline text as requested. I'm happy with the answer but for bonus I'm adding in the following condition of the source data having similar exceptions but wanting them to be grouped together like the unauthorized exceptions being grouped.

What I have so far:

```sql
Select r.Exception, stuff(
   (select distinct FK + ',' 
    from [Table] wr 
    where r.Exception = wr.Exception 
    for XML PATH('')),1,0,''
) as [FKs]
From [Table] r
Group by r.Exception
```

Comment: database name and version please

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server (starting with 2017)

```
SELECT Exception, STRING_AGG (FK, ',') AS FK
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Exception;
```

OR

[Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)