# Concatenate/aggregate strings with JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml

This might be a simple question for those who are experienced in working with JSON in SQL Server. I found this interesting way of aggregating strings using `FOR XML` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings).

```
create table #t (id int, name varchar(20))

insert into #t
values (1, 'Matt'), (1, 'Rocks'), (2, 'Stylus')

select  id
    ,Names = stuff((select ', ' + name as [text()]
    from #t xt
    where xt.id = t.id
    for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
from #t t
group by id
```

How can I do the same using `JSON` instead of `XML`?

Comment: I'm baffled.  Why would you want to do that?  If you are using the more recent versions of SQL Server, then forget this and use `string_agg()`.  Aggregate string concatenation should really be a basic function in SQL.  Oh wait.  It *is* in the standard, but SQL Server has chosen a different name.

Comment: In SQL Server 2017 and later, use STRING_AGG. In previous versions, using JSON is little better than using XML. Why do you want JSON specifically? PS: there are duplicates for this already

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you point to the standard? (Intentional pun, knowing you have to pay to get the standard, but who knows)

Comment: @GordonLinoff based on [this article](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg) it looks like LISTAGG is one of those functions with really bad conformance across all databases. Which isn't that rare with SQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using 2016. It doesn't have the STRING_AGG function but has JSON. I want to know which one performs better and I guess JSON would be the answer.

Comment: @TheEsnSiavashi . . . Although you could -- no doubt -- adapt the solution for JSON, why bother?  The XML solution has always been a work-around.  It was developed before SQL Server supported JSON.  Eventually, you'll upgrade the database and you can then use the correct solution, the built-in function designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot replace the XML approach with JSON. This string concatenation works due to some XML inner peculiarities, which are not the same in JSON.

Starting with SQL Server 2017 onwards you can use `STRING_AGG()`, but with earlier versions, the XML approach is the way to go.

## Some background and a hint

First the hint: The code you showed is not safe for the XML special characters. Check my example below.

First I declare a simple XML

```
DECLARE  @xml XML=
N'<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b>2</b>
  <b>3</b>
  <c>
    <d>x</d>
    <d>y</d>
    <d>z</d>
  </c>
</a>';
```

--The XPath `.` tells the XML engine to use *the current node* (and all within)
--Therefore this will return any content within the XML

```
SELECT @xml.value('.','varchar(100)')
```

--You can specify the path to get 123 or xyz

```
SELECT @xml.query('/a/b').value('.','varchar(100)')
SELECT @xml.query('//d').value('.','varchar(100)')
```

Now your issue to concatenate tabular data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('This'),('will'),('concatenate'),('magically'),('Forbidden Characters & > <');
```

--The simple `FOR XML` query will tag the column with `<SomeString>` and each row with `<row>`:

```
SELECT SomeString FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row');
```

--But we can create the same without any tags:
--Attention: Look closely, that the result - even without tags - is XML typed and looks like a hyper link in SSMS.

```
SELECT SomeString AS [*] FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('');
```

--Now we can use as a *sub-select* within a surrounding query.
--The result is returned **as string**, not XML typed anymore... Look at the forbidden chars!

```
SELECT
 (SELECT SomeString FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'))
,(SELECT SomeString AS [*] FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH(''))
```

--We can use `,TYPE` to enforce the sub-select to be treated as XML typed itself
--This allows to use `.query()` and/or `.value()`

```
SELECT
 (SELECT SomeString FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE).query('data(//SomeString)').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
,(SELECT SomeString AS [*] FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

XQuery's `.data()` can be used to concatenate named elements with blanks in between.
XQuery's `.value()` must be used to re-escpae forbidden characters.

Comment: Great in detail explanations, +1 from my side!

Comment: Good explanation. But I'm confused as whats the answer to my question. Because u say we cannot do the same with JSON but @GordonLinoff says "you could -- no doubt -- adapt the solution for JSON" in his above comment.

Comment: @TheEsnSiavashi There is no Json without item names. The rest would be ugly string manipulations...

Comment: This is a great explanation, but it doesn't work if `SomeString` contains characters that are invalid in XML. The `, TYPE` conversion fails with an error.

Comment: @GPHemsley In this case you can wrap `SomeString` with `select some string as [*]  for xml path('') `. This will do all the escaping implicitly.