# SQL Server Select Query With Join/Sub Query On Same Table To Create A Master Field Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a weird query, and I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible (Efficiently anyway) as it's a bit of a weird situation.

Let's say I have the following data called `ProductTable`. They are product variants with one product being the master product (Default). They are grouped by `ProductKey`.

```
VariantId, ProductKey, Name, Description, Values, Master
1, 1, Name One, Description One, {large json chunk}, true
2, 1, Name Two, Description Two, {small json chunk}, false
3, 1, Name Three, Description Three, {small json chunk}, false
4, 2, Name Four, Description Four, {small json chunk}, false
5, 2, Name Five, Description Five, {small json chunk}, true
```

I want to be able to query for non master variants, but append the `[Values]` column of the master product to the query as a column called `[MasterValues]`. So if I queried simply for all non master products, something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductTable 
WHERE [Master] = 0
```

I would get the following result:

```
VariantId, ProductKey, Name, Description, Values, Master
2, 1, Name Two, Description Two, {small json chunk}, false
3, 1, Name Three, Description Three, {small json chunk}, false
4, 2, Name Four, Description Four, {small json chunk}, false
```

However, I would like to have the following column `[MasterValues]` that is populated by the `[values]` column of the master product for that `productGroup`:

```
VariantId, ProductKey, Name, Description, Values, Master, MasterValues
2, 1, Name Two, Description Two, {small json chunk}, false, {large json chunk from variant id 1}
3, 1, Name Three, Description Three, {small json chunk}, false, {large json chunk from variant id 1}
4, 2, Name Four, Description Four, {small json chunk}, false, {large json chunk from variant id 2}
```

I realise this is a bit weird, but is it possible? I thought maybe a Join of some sort on the same table?

Comment: Is the large json chunk coming from a different table?

Comment: @CR7SMS no, as per above example it's the same table and only from the master variant of the same productgroup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings This link provides multiple ways to do what you are looking for. If you are using SQL 2017, then you can using STRING_AGG function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the relationship between variant to master products is many to one, you can get away with a self-join here. Basically, we're going to select all the variant products from the `ProductTable` table, then join to the (same) `ProductTable` to find the master product.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
    pa.* --this is not a best practice, ideally you should list out all the selected columns individually
    , pb.Values
FROM ProductTable pa --'pa' is the variant, while 'pb' is the master
INNER JOIN ProductTable pb --you may wish to do a left join here if there is not always a master product for a given variant
ON pb.ProductKey = pa.ProductKey
    AND pb.Master = 1
WHERE pa.Master = 0
```