# List Unique Column Values and Subtotal a Column Using Classic ASP SQL in MS Windows 2000 Server

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Batch_Number, RM_Code, RM_Qty, RM_Lot_Number
```

The table has multiple records because a Batch_Number may use an RM_Code (Raw Material Code) from different RM_Lot_Number and loading of RM_Code, the ingredients, are at different stages of a batch cook, where each load of ingredient has a record. Please help me with an SQL statement, or any other solution other than looping because it takes long, that will display the following:

```
Batch_Number, RM_Code, Total_RM_Qty, Comma_Separated_List_Of_Unique_RM_Lot_Number
```

I am using Classic ASP. Please note also that STRING_AGG does not work in Microsoft Windows 2000 Server Service Pack 4 that I am using. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Comment: Classic ASP? Is that still even a thing?

Comment: On Charlieface: The FOR XML PATH does not work also in MS Windows 2000 Server.

Comment: On Mitch Wheat: Yes, it is a reality. Some are indeed collector or preserver of "antiques", and if they find a solution for the thing to function in the present time in acceptable manner or efficiency, then immeasurable contentment and happiness comes naturally :).

Comment: along with all the security vulnerabilities that won't be fixed,.....