# Is there any function which would help me in concatenating second table ids without repeating rows of first table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with cte (PersonID, FirstName, name) 
as
(
    select 
        p.PersonID, p.FirstName, dep.name 
    from 
        [PersonDepMapping] map 
    inner join 
        person p on map.personid = p.PersonID
    inner join 
        Department dep on dep.DepartmentID = map.DepartmentID
)
select * 
from cte
```

This is what I am getting now:

```
1   Kim     English
1   Kim     Economics
2   Gytis   Engineering
3   Peggy   Mathematics
```

I want an output something like this:

```
1   Kim     English, Economics
2   Gytis   Engineering
3   Peggy   Mathematics
```

Can anyone please help? I couldn't find any answer that could help me
get what I need - do I need to use `GROUP BY` or `FOR XML PATH` or something else entirely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `string_agg()` (available since SQL Server 2017):

```
select p.PersonID, p.FirstName,
       string_agg(dep.name, ',')
from PersonDepMapping map inner join
     person p
     on map.personid = p.PersonID join
     Department dep
     on dep.DepartmentID = map.DepartmentID
group by p.PersonID, p.FirstName;
```

Comment: What if i am having multiple joins and many select items then adding all items in group by will cause a problem In that case what I can do?

Comment: @devloper . . . There should be no problem.  This is just another aggregation function.

Comment: Lost the "Close as Duplicate" button again?