# Comma separated values in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL server. I have a select statement that has number of columns queried from joining more than 4 tables, and the result table is shown as below,

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | File1 | Table1 | Column1 |
| 1 | File1 | Table1 | Column2 |
| 1 | File1 | Table2 | Column1 |

Here, the values of Column4 are distinct that must be grouped and the result that I require is,

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | File1 | Table1 | Column1, Column2 |
| 1 | File2 | Table2 | Column1 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

you can use STRING_AGG

```
select column1,column2,column3,STRING_AGG(column4,',') as column4
from adds
group by column1,column2,column3
```

base Data

```
create table adds(
column1 varchar(100),   column2 varchar(100),   column3 varchar(100),   column4 varchar(100)
)
insert into adds values
(1, 'File1',    'Table1'    ,'Column1')
,(1,'File1',    'Table1'    ,'Column2')
,(1,'File1',    'Table2'    ,'Column1')
```

Comment: In this approach, we need to add the every other column as group by columns. Do we have any other approach, so that, we dont need to group by with so many columns?

Comment: There are other methods, but this method is easier and better
You can use CTE and Windows Faction like this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings