# Set Rowcount affecting embedded scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that has a scalar valued function embedded in it. The function selects names from various rows from a table and concatenates them with comma as a separator. For e.g. ABC, DEF, XYZ. I have set ROWCOUNT to only 1 for the query because I want only 1 record. The problem is that if I set ROWCOUNT to 1 my scalar function yields unexpected results i.e. ABC instead of ABC, DEF, XYZ.

Can anybody help? I am restricted to use ROWCOUNT only instead of TOP clause.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use ROWCOUNT instead of the TOP clause?

Comment: Further to Aaron's comment.. @@ROWCOUNT() is a function for returning the number of rows in a result set. You cannot use ROWCOUNT to select only the TOP n rows.

Comment: furthermore, there is no order to a set, and SQL is set based... without an explicit ORDER BY your result value is not guaranteed. You also need to ensure that ORDER BY is deterministic, so you need a WITH TIES clause or a tiebreaker.

Comment: And this is why `SET ROWCOUNT` was deprecated and replaced with the TOP clause: changing it has global, unintended side-effects.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse - You are talking about the [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) function not the [`SET ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) statement.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - AFAIK it isn't actually officially deprecated for `SELECT` queries though I don't see why they don't.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, right.  Perhaps I meant "despised"?

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah yes, my bad. Never used ROWCOUNT to do this sort of thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET ROWCOUNT` will affect the rows returned by both the outer `SELECT` statement and the outer level of any `SELECT` statements contained in the scalar UDF.

So this isn't possible through use of `SET ROWCOUNT` alone unless you can change the definition of the Scalar UDF.

I assume that you are using the [undocumented and un guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136) variable assignment approach. If you change to the `XML PATH` approach then as the top most `SELECT` only returns 1 row anyway it will remain unaffected by the `SET ROWCOUNT 1` command.

#### Example Code

```
    USE tempdb;
GO
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Concat1(@number INT = 0)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
    AS
      BEGIN
          DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(max)

          SELECT @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ',','') + name
          FROM   master..spt_values
          WHERE  number = @number

          RETURN @Result
      END
GO
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Concat2(@number INT = 0)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
    AS
      BEGIN
          RETURN
            (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + name AS [text()]
                           FROM   master..spt_values
                           WHERE  number = @number
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))
      END
GO
    SET ROWCOUNT 1;

    SELECT dbo.Concat1(number) AS Concat1,
           dbo.Concat2(number) AS Concat2
    FROM   master..spt_values
    WHERE  number = 1

    DROP FUNCTION dbo.Concat1, dbo.Concat2
```

#### Results

```
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Concat1 |                                                                              Concat2                                                                               |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rpc     | rpc,yes,autoclose,published,WINDOWS/NT,trusted,ignore duplicate keys,binary,varbinary,primary,NULL,Xact,NUL,GRANT,system table,disable_def_cnst_check,default disk |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```