# Is there way to know if select examining firs value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need:

```
SELECT 
    @SQLString5 = 
        COALESCE(@SQLString5 + ' ', '')
        + CASE(IF FIRST THEN ' FROM ' ELSE ' full OUTER JOIN ')
        + 'VV' + ZZZ.ZZ
    FROM ZZZ
```

e.g. I'm building string by all nodes, and rule of building first node string part should be different, FIRST here is pseudocode.

is it possible?

Comment: Use `XML PATH`. This approach to string concatenation is [not guaranteed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number`, but I think more neat is to use `isnull`(or `coalesce`, but for 2 values it's better to use `isnull`) for this, here's my little trick:

```
select
    @SQLString5 = 
    isnull(@SQLString5 + ' full outer join ' , ' from ') + 'VV' + @SOMEVALUE
from ZZZ
```

Actually don't know why do you adding `@SOMEVALUE` variable instead of data from `ZZZ` table

Comment: I'm adding data from ZZZ )

Comment: so I think you don't need row_number, just use isnull for that