# Why does one SQL query return different results than one with a filter that is always true?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL query inside a user-defined scalar function:

```
declare @csv varchar(8000)

select  @csv = 
    COALESCE(@csv + ', ' +  CAST(CallID as varchar(10)),
                            CAST(CallID as varchar(10)))
from    calls
where   1=1             --@csv = '6097'
        callid = callid --@csv = '1, 2, 3'...
        callid <= 10000 --always true, expected result (@csv = '1, 2, 3'...)
order by callid

select @csv
```

If I use the 1=1 where condition, I get @csv = '6097' (the max CallID in the table). If I use callid=callid, callid <= 10000, I get the expected result: @csv = '1, 2, 3, '… This is also the result if I remove either the WHERE or the ORDER BY clause.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen? I have another case of it happening, but the function is a bit more complicated. I created a brand new table with one ID int not null primary key field, populated it with 1-6097, and tried the query above, and it never gives me the unexpected result of '6097'. This is the most confusing issue I have had with SQL Server, so if anyone has a direction in which to point me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot see anything wrong with this code could you please show your function's definition as well ? does it show unexpected results only when executed inside a function or even just executing the query itself gives the unexpected results ??

Comment: It happens even if I take the body of the function (above) and run it in a new query window. But please see my latest comment to RBarryYoung regarding the new table with the same data giving different results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior)

Comment: See @Martin Smith's excellent answer of why you *cannot* guarantee the above concatenation of rows will work. Also, his linked comment to VarDerNorth identifies efficient mechanisms for concatenation that do work across all cases.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. His first link isn't relevant, I don't think, because I'm not applying any functions or operators on my ORDER BY columns. But I kept reading, and see that apparently it's "by design" to not execute all the statements I issue in the SELECT… THANK YOU for the information!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your callid column is coming back NULL on the next to last row.  This causes your accumulator to reset in the 1=1 case, and causing the callid=callid to fail in the other case (because NULL=NULL is False).

The solution is to wrap your callid usage in COALESCE Calls also.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that CallID is the PK; i.e. NOT NULL.

Comment: in that case I would suggest posting enough info that we can reproduce the problem ourselves.  Because at this point I really cannot imagine anything else that would match these specific conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing that. When I made a brand new table, I don't get the same results (I get CSV every time). And here's another curve-ball: I did SELECT CallID INTO c FROM Calls, then changed the query to use FROM c, and I always get CSV now too. The same happens, if I put a TOP 100000 clause in with FROM Calls. Sorry if I'm being unclear. Any ideas, or how can I post a better example? Thanks so much!