# Unexpected result with COALESCE Function SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + DriversTransportDetails.DriverName from DriversTransportDetails 

select  trID, @combinedString as C 
from DriversTransportDetails 
group by DriversTransportDetails.trID
```

This is my code, I have table called `DriversTransportDetails` which contains columns `trID` (`int`) and `driverName` (`nvarchar`)

`trID` is not unique so `trID` can be in multiple rows depends on drivers, ex :

```
TrID  DriverName
1     Tony
1     Rony
2     Jeorge
3     Jim
```

I want to `COALESCE` driver name rows into one row, desired result :

```
TrID   C
1      Tony, Rony
2      Jeorge
3      Jim
```

The problem is the result is not correct, it shows all drivers combined into column c, like this :

```
TrID   C
1      Tony, Rony, Jeorge, Jim
2      Tony, Rony, Jeorge, Jim
3      Tony, Rony, Jeorge, Jim
```

What's the problem ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: you could create scalar valued function to return coalesced string based on unique TrId like: `select ... dbo.GetListOfDrivers(TrId) as C`

Comment: it is at the same direction, but i am using sql 2008 and COALESCE function.

Comment: @Milen I would not bother using a function for this - you can do it inline quite simply; a function does nothing but save a few characters at the cost of significant overhead.

Comment: understood @AaronBertrand

Comment: for those who marked this as duplicated question, where is the answer ?!

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar - Use `XML PATH` per the dupe. Using `Coalesce`/ aggregate concatenation [is not guaranteed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136) and can only be done in a correlated way if you create a scalar UDF.

Comment: You'll have to change it a bit, of course, but [you get to the answer(s) by scrolling down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/451441/61305).

Comment: thank you very much, but honestly i do not know what are you talking about (XML PATH),anyway, i am trying to do that by COALESCE function because i am planning to use it in Crystal Reports, is XML PATH available also  with CR ?

Comment: No idea. Can't you run arbitrary SQL? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/179c1/1)