# Looking for Name of a Particular SQL Server Pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was messing around in SQL and I stumbled onto this code mostly by accident and for reasons I can't explain works at least in SQL Server 2008.

I wouldn't normally ask this on SO but I don't what I should be searching for, and I was hoping to find out.

```
  DECLARE @Number INT = 1

  SELECT @Number = @Number + N
  FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2), (3), (4)) vals(N)) vals

  PRINT @Number
```

This adds 1 + 2 +3 + 4 and produces 10.

Why does this work and does this pattern have a name? Is it an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's an anti pattern.

It isn't guaranteed to work ([see recent Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809233/using-order-by-results-in-wrong-sum)) and will inhibit parallelism. Just use `SUM`.

```
  DECLARE @Number INT = 1

  SELECT @Number+= SUM(N)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2), (3), (4)) vals(N)) vals

  PRINT @Number
```

It is similar to another old technique for concatenating strings that is [also not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/73226).

> Why does this work

When it does work correctly the variable is incremented by `N` for each row in the source. However this is execution plan dependant as the linked Connect item shows.

Comment: Oh, dear. Thanks so much for the links. This is what I was looking for, because I was planning to use it for formatting currencies. I will need to reconsider.