# put ascii value into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, ascii

Is it Available to put ascii values into variable in sql server 2008 r2? I trying this code:

```
declare @thechars varchar(15)
declare @theascii varchar(50)
declare @position int

set @thechars = 'somechar'
set @theascii = ''
set @position = 1

while(@position<16)
begin
   set @theascii = @theascii+convert(varchar,ascii(substring(@thechars ,@position,1)))
   set @position = @position + 1
end

print '-------------------------'
print 'the ascii is ' + @theascii 
print '-------------------------'
```

but the result just like this:

```
-------------------------   

-------------------------
```

is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: To troublehoot, output some values inside your loop so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
while(@position <= LEN(@thechars))
```

I have no idea why you hard code `16` in your version.

Trying to extract a `SUBSTRING` after the length of the string returns `NULL` which then means the whole concatenated string is `NULL`.

If you must do that then an alternative is to replace `NULL` with empty string prior to concatenation.

```
SET @theascii += ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),ASCII(SUBSTRING(@thechars ,@position,1))),'')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I think I should try to not hard code my program from now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to do something like this following.

NB, I've included the idea of a Tally\Numbers table as opposed to using a loop.
Tally tables are typically regarded as being more performant.
Please read up about them.

```
DECLARE  @InputText     VARCHAR(50)     = 'Hello, world!'
        ,@ASCIIString   VARCHAR(200)    = ''


;WITH TallyCTE (n) AS
--  You may want to create a physical Tally table - Google & read up!
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM syscolumns
)
SELECT @ASCIIString = @ASCIIString + CAST(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputText, n, 1)) AS VARCHAR) + ', '
FROM TallyCTE
WHERE n <= LEN(@InputText)


PRINT 'The ASCII lookup values are; ' + LEFT(@ASCIIString, LEN(@ASCIIString)-1)
```

Comment: This approach [isn't guaranteed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/73226). You would need another approach e.g. `XML PATH`

Comment: True, but the process can be modified to show each ascii lookup code for each character, making ordering unnecessary.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to work (and sometimes doesn't) even with no order by in sight.

Answer (score -1):

Do not hardcode the length in WHILE LOOP. Sometimes the given input length may exceeds your hardcoded value. But still you will get some output. If the length is lesser than the value, you will get the empty value. If you use 'SELECT' statement instead of PRINT you will get NULL as output.

Handle this issue

> Replace the hardcoded value with **LEN(@thechars)**

Or

> Handle **NULL** :  ISNULL(CONVERT (VARCHAR,ASCII(SUBSTRING(@thechars ,@position,1))),'')

First one is best

Comment: How is this different from the two points I made 9 hours previously?

Comment: Sorry I used mobile device. While scrolling your answer skipped. Just only saw your answer. Your is good explanation.