# Concatenating multiple values into a single string as a subquery without using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two row values from table C:

```
Select Name FROM Table C Where AccountID = 123
```

```html
      COL1
Row 1 |Ricky|
Row 2 |Roxy |
```

I want to be able to select both of these two values in a *SubQuery* that will be used in a larger query. So that it displays "**Ricky, Roxy"**

How can this be done without declaring a variable?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server string aggregation"

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Comment: What about if I was to use a variable?

Comment: Don't use a variable. The behaviour is not documented, and you can get unexpected results depending on internal access paths. A recently answered [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32267590/1048425) where the user had encountered this exact unexpected behaviour when using a variable to concatenate strings. Just read Aaron's article, it not only contains numerous solutions, it also compares performance on all of them. What more could you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COL1 = STUFF ((SELECT ',' + COL1 FROM tableC WHERE AccountID=123
FOR XML PATH(''), Type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
1,1,'')
```

This will return all account 123 COL1 values as one column, with commas separating values.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3f09/5)

Comment: @SebastianRoces  hard to say why without knowing your table schema.  i've updated my answer with a SQL Fiddle showing it works in SQL Server 2008.