# SUM of dynamic Columns in PIVOT table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, powerpivot, pivotviewer, activepivot

I have a Dynamic PIVOT query in which Columns are dynamically generated.

My table:  ATTENDANCE_MASTER
Contains:  ID, Stud_id, ATT_DATE, PRESENT

which stores data like:

```
ID  Stud_id ATT_DATE   PRESENT
1     1     2015-08-1    1
2     2     2015-08-1    0
3     3     2015-08-1    1
4     1     2015-08-2    0
5     2     2015-08-2    1
6     3     2015-08-2    1
```

I have created PIVOT Query

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(ATT_DATE)
  FROM (SELECT p.ATT_DATE FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE_MASTER AS p
  GROUP BY p.ATT_DATE) AS x;

SET @sql = N'SELECT Stud_id, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.ATT_DATE, p.Stud_id, p.PRESENT FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE_MASTER AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRESENT) FOR ATT_DATE IN ('+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I need sum of columns like

```
Stud_ID  2015-08-01   2015-08-2 2015-08-3 Total
1            1            0         1      2
2            1            1         1      3
3            1            1         0      2
4            0            0         1      1
```

Please suggest me solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I know how to make sum of Static columns, But I dont know how to sum of dynamic columns

Comment: What output do you have for now?

Comment: What is dynamic here? the number of date columns?

Comment: Now I have above output except Total Column

Comment: Yes, Date's Column names are Dynamic @ bmsqldev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd firstly recommend not using variable concatenation to create your column list. [It's behaviour is undefined and can be unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/1048425). Instead use SQL Server's XML extensions:

```
SET @Columns = (SELECT  N', p.' + QUOTENAME(p.Att_Date)
                FROM    dbo.ATTENDANCE_MASTER AS p
                GROUP BY p.ATT_DATE
                ORDER BY p.ATT_DATE
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

Then you can simply use `@Columns` to create an expression for the total, so using:

```
', Total = ' + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ' + p.['), 1, 3, '')
```

You get something like:

```
, Total = p.[2015-08-01] + p.[2015-08-02]
```

Which you can add to your dynamic SQL, so for a full working example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T ([ID] int, [Stud_id] int, [ATT_DATE] datetime, [PRESENT] int);

INSERT INTO #T ([ID], [Stud_id], [ATT_DATE], [PRESENT])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
    (2, 2, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 0),
    (3, 3, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 1),
    (4, 1, '2015-08-02 00:00:00', 0),
    (5, 2, '2015-08-02 00:00:00', 1),
    (6, 3, '2015-08-02 00:00:00', 1);

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);             

SET @Columns = (SELECT  N', p.' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), p.Att_Date, 111), '/', '-'))
                FROM    #T AS p
                GROUP BY p.ATT_DATE
                ORDER BY p.ATT_DATE
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

SET @sql = N'SELECT Stud_id, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + ', Total = ' + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ' + p.['), 1, 3, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.ATT_DATE, p.Stud_id, p.PRESENT FROM #T AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRESENT) FOR ATT_DATE IN ('+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I have one more query, How can I use two aggregate functions in this, Like Sum and Count.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `GROUP BY WITH CUBE` to get total in following:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(ATT_DATE)
  FROM (SELECT p.ATT_DATE FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE_MASTER AS p
  GROUP BY p.ATT_DATE) AS x;

SET @sql = N'SELECT Stud_id, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.ATT_DATE, p.Stud_id, p.PRESENT 
  FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE_MASTER AS p
  GROUP BY p.ATT_DATE, p.Stud_id, p.PRESENT 
  WITH CUBE
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(PRESENT) FOR ATT_DATE IN ('+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```