# Avoid overlapping ranges via SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Please Help me to find the SQL Query 
I want to restrict user to enter duplicate value between From and To.

I have written the Query but it's not working, Here is my Query

```
SELECT intpkPciid 
FROM Table1  
WHERE @intFrom(userinputdata)  BETWEEN intFrom AND intTO
```

[image]

Comment: Query?  SQL? Or do you just want to know how to format a string?

Comment: Actually my requirement is:- These numbers From and To are related with some Package id.  So i want to update all data in another table column like  9-10,5-5-6,90-100,100-200. SQL Query i want. Value From and To i can Concate but in comma Seperated i want pls help me out.

Comment: If its sql then add that tag.

Comment: What happened to your original question re. comma-separated values? The nature of your question seems to have completely changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all your rows into comma-separated values using `COALESCE`:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max)

SELECT @test = COALESCE(@test + ',', '') + CAST(intFrom as varchar) + '-' + CAST(intTo as varchar)
from Table1

SELECT @test
```

Your question seems to have completely changed, but you can avoid row entries that overlap using:

```
SELECT intpkPciid FROM Table1 WHERE @intFrom <= intTO AND @intTo >= intFrom
```

Comment: Are you aware that `SELECT @test = @test  + ... ` is unreliable? [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/5070879)

Comment: Point taken @lad2025. However, it does usually work, especially where the query plan is as simple as this one. i.e. a single clustered index scan.

Comment: i don't have 15 reputation so  i am not able to mark it as answered.

Comment: From my understanding, you can't vote up the answer until you have 15 reputation but you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @ImranAzam - you can mark an answer as "accepted" with less than 15 reputation - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts. You can't vote below that level.