# Assigning multiple rows to non-table variable

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to understand what happens here (one of the answers to this question: [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)):

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + Name 
FROM People
```

So I have an exemplary table 'test' with data:

```
Col1
----
abc
xyz
```

Now I execute:

```
DECLARE @Concatenation VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Concatenation = COALESCE(@Concatenation + ', ', '') + Col1 FROM test
Select @Concatenation
```

And as a result I have a single result `abc, xyz`

If I execute:

```
DECLARE @Concatenation VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Concatenation = Col1 FROM test
Select @Concatenation
```

I get a single result `xyz`

The question is why doing an assignment like `select @variable = @variable + column` causes the `@variable` to iterate over the whole column? And if I do it like `select @variable = column` which record from the column is returned? Random?

Comment: that is undocumented hack an yes it works but you should use xml trick to do this.

Comment: For your last question: the assignment will use the **last** record. I guess it iterates through all records anyway, and with the `coalesce` method, it will actually store all records.

Comment: @HoneyBadger how do you define last record? There's no clustered or any index whatsoever.

Comment: @zaptask That depends on the optimizer of `sql server`, if you dont tell it with an `order by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do instead:

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + name
                FROM    People
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

The first example in your question is a hack and works just by accident. See these threads:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/383641

[nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior)

The second one may return you any value because you are not specifying order.

Comment: What do you mean it works by accident? Is there a more verbose description of the problem? Is it SQL Server specific? T-SQL sepecific? Does it work in other dialects?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I've read, this is a "hack that works by accident" as well. There is no function in `sql server` like `group_concat` of `mysql`.

Comment: @zaptask, I mean this is undocumented feature and can be just removed from future releases of `SQL Server`. And there is some trouble with that. I remember I have read about it. I will search for that.

Comment: Here is the link on discussion of this hack https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/383641