# Concatenate the result of an ordered String_Split in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

In a SqlServer database I use, the database name is something like `StackExchange.Audio.Meta`, or `StackExchange.Audio` or `StackOverflow` . By sheer luck this is also the url for a website. I only need split it on the dots and reverse it: `meta.audio.stackexchange`. Adding `http://` and `.com` and I'm done. Obviously `Stackoverflow` doesn't need any reversing.

Using the SqlServer 2016 [string_split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) function I can easy split and reorder its result:

```
select value
from string_split(db_name(),'.')
order by row_number() over( order by (select 1)) desc
```

This gives me

```
|  Value        |
-----------------
| Meta          |
| Audio         |
| StackExchange |
```

As I need to have the url in a variable I hoped to concatenate it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194887/578411) so my attempt looks like this:

```
declare @revname nvarchar(150)
select @revname = coalesce(@revname +'.','')  + value
from string_split(db_name(),'.')
order by row_number() over( order by (select 1)) desc
```

However this only returns me the last value, `StackExchange`. I already noticed the warnings on that answer that this trick only works for certain execution plans as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515).

The problem seems to be caused by the `order by` clause. Without that I get all values, but then in the wrong order. I tried to a add `ltrim`and `rtrim` function as suggested in the Microsoft article as well as a subquery but so far without luck.

Is there a way I can nudge the Sql Server 2016 Query Engine to concatenate the ordered result from that `string_split` in a variable?

I do know I can use `for XML` or even a plain cursor to get the result I need but I don't want to give up this elegant solution yet.

As I'm running this on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer I can't use functions, as we lack the permission to create those. I can do Stored procedures but I hoped I could evade those.

I prepared a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.avp/query/506713) to experiment with. The database names to expect are either without dots, aka `StackOverflow`, with 1 dot: `StackOverflow.Meta` or 2 dots, `StackExchange.Audio.Meta, the full list of databases is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.avp/query/506737)

Comment: Why not http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.avp/query/506813? Oh and regarding your desire to use the variable assignment method there is never any guarantee that it will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136

Comment: I realize I'm using undefined behavior so I accept that as an answer as well.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but if you are generating URLs with all this string manipulation, why not just have a lookup table instead? In your SEDE query you are already doing some funky stuff (`when 'audio` then `Avp`) so isn't it better to have a translation table for all this?

Comment: @DavidG there are only two special cases so far and as I have to copy that over each time, I didn't want to have anything that needs maintenance when new sites/.databases are added. But I had considered that, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things. You could use `PARSENAME`:

```
SELECT 'http://' + PARSENAME(db_name(),1) + 
       ISNULL('.' + PARSENAME(db_name(),2),'') + ISNULL('.'+PARSENAME(db_name(),3),'') 
       + '.com'
```

Comment: This works well, and I like how it is totally ignoring my attempt  ;). It is not where [parsename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) was originally designed for but I wouldn't have checked or tried this if you (and Martin) didn't point it out to me. Thanks.

Comment: @rene I just thought that your approach was overly complicated, sorry. Hadn't seen MartinSmith comment, but I'm more confident now that I read it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why I have the Presentation Sequence (PS) in my split function.  People often scoff at using a UDF for such items, but it is generally a one-time hit to parse something for later consumption.

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('meta.audio.stackexchange','.')
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       meta
2       audio
3       stackexchange
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('meta.audio.stackexchange','.')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(max))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(max)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Replace(@String, @SubStr + @delimeter, '')
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: A UDF function is great and I love and would have used that. Unfortunately on SEDE we don't have create function permission.

Comment: @rene Still refreshing for use mere mortals to see someone the 22K reps ask a question.

Comment: Well, yes after banging my head for 2 hours I already spend so much time on it that I didn't want to give up....

Answer (score 1):

Probably less elegant solution but it takes only a few lines and works with any number of dots.

```
;with cte as (--build xml
  select 1 num, cast('<str><s>'+replace(db_name(),'.','</s><s>')+'</s></str>' as xml) str
)
,x as (--make table from xml
    select row_number() over(order by num) rn, --add numbers to sort later
       t.v.value('.[1]','varchar(50)') s
    from cte cross apply cte.str.nodes('str/s') t(v)
)
--combine into string
select STUFF((SELECT '.' + s AS [text()]
            FROM x
            order by rn desc --in reverse order
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '' ) name
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can nudge the Sql Server 2016 Query Engine to concatenate the ordered result from that string_split in a variable?

You can just use `CONCAT`:

```
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @URL = CONCAT(value, '.', @URL) FROM STRING_SPLIT(DB_NAME(), '.')
SET @URL = CONCAT('http://', LOWER(@URL), 'com');
```

The reversal is accomplished by the order of parameters to `CONCAT`. [Here's an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mechanics/query/653297).

It changes `StackExchange.Garage.Meta` to `http://meta.garage.stackexchange.com`.

This can be used to split and reverse strings in general, but note that it does leave a trailing delimiter. I'm sure you could add some logic or a `COALESCE` in there to make that not happen.

Also note that vNext will be adding [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the 'X' of this XY problem, and to address the HTTPS switch (especially for Meta sites) and some other site name changes, I've written the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/782314/mapping-for-database-site-url) which outputs all site names in the format used on the [network site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

```
SELECT name,
  LOWER('https://' +
    IIF(PATINDEX('%.Mathoverflow%', name) > 0,
    IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', name) > 0, 'meta.mathoverflow.net', 'mathoverflow.net'),
      IIF(PATINDEX('%.Ubuntu%', name) > 0,
      IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', name) > 0, 'meta.askubuntu.com', 'askubuntu.com'),
        IIF(PATINDEX('StackExchange.%', name) > 0,
          CASE SUBSTRING(name, 15, 200)
          WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
          WHEN 'Audio.Meta' THEN 'video.meta'
          WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
          WHEN 'Beer.Meta' THEN 'alcohol.meta'
          WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
          WHEN 'CogSci.Meta' THEN 'psychology.meta'
          WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
          WHEN 'Garage.Meta' THEN 'mechanics.meta'
          WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
          WHEN 'Health.Meta' THEN 'medicalsciences.meta'
          WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
          WHEN 'Moderators.Meta' THEN 'communitybuilding.meta'
          WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
          WHEN 'Photography.Meta' THEN 'photo.meta'
          WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
          WHEN 'Programmers.Meta' THEN 'softwareengineering.meta'
          WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
          WHEN 'Vegetarian.Meta' THEN 'vegetarianism.meta'
          WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
          WHEN 'Writers.Meta' THEN 'writing.meta'
          ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 15, 200)
          END + '.stackexchange.com',
          IIF(PATINDEX('StackOverflow.%', name) > 0,
            CASE SUBSTRING(name, 15, 200)
            WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
            WHEN 'Br.Meta' THEN 'pt.meta'
            ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 15, 200)
            END + '.stackoverflow.com',
            IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', name) > 0,
              'meta.' + SUBSTRING(name, 0, PATINDEX('%.Meta', name)) + '.com',
              name + '.com'
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ) + '/'
  )
  FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 5
```