# I don't understand how the SQL statement returns this answer

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @EmployeeIds VARCHAR(200)

SELECT @EmployeeIds = ISNULL (@EmployeeIds + ',', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5))
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE Gender = 'Male'

PRINT @EmployeeIds
```

Do you have any idea how we got the 1,3,4,5,6,9,10 ? I mean here how we got the answer as an array and not like this:

```
1
3
4
5
6
9
10
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 4):

> How we got the answer as an array?

It isn't an array. It is a comma delimited string. It was generated through assigning to the variable `@EmployeeIds` multiple times. Once for each row in `tblEmployee` that matched the `WHERE` clause.

`@EmployeeIds` is null to begin with. The first row is encountered and has ID of 1.

```
  @EmployeeIds= ISNULL (@EmployeeIds + ',', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5))
≡ @EmployeeIds= ISNULL (NULL + ',', '') + '1' /*Substituting in variable and column values*/
≡ @EmployeeIds= ISNULL (NULL, '') + '1'
≡ @EmployeeIds= '' + '1'
```

So @EmployeeIds is `1` after the first row.

The second row is processed and has `ID` of `3`

```
  @EmployeeIds= ISNULL (@EmployeeIds + ',', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5))
≡ @EmployeeIds= ISNULL ('1' + ',', '') + '3' /*Substituting in variable and column values*/
≡ @EmployeeIds= ('1' + ',')  + '3'
≡ @EmployeeIds= '1,3'
```

And so on. This is not a guaranteed approach to string concatenation. It can and does fail and is specifically warned against by Microsoft.

[Some example warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136)

Future versions will include a `STRING_AGG` function. For now the best alternative is [`XML PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451441/73226)

Comment: Thanks.It is well explained !!