# String aggregate using a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014, string-concatenation

Is is okay to use a variable to concatenate a value from several rows ( as an implicit aggregate function )? It seems to work fine on my machine, but I haven't seen it recommended.

```
declare @v_str varchar(4000) = ''
select top 5 @v_str = @v_str + ',' + city_name from city_table order by city_name
print @v_str
```

Comment: Assuming you're using SQL Server the generally accepted method based documented features uses XML and `Stuff()` to assemble the string. If you have a look at the "Related" links for this question (over on the right side of the page) you should find some examples. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: On thing that you should be aware of: **[nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/1778606)
"The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined."