# Remove ON DELETE CASCADE on foreign keys for several tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables with a foreign key constraint that has the option `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Every table belongs to the same schema called `datasets`.

I'm able to retrieve the complete list of tables using :

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='datasets'
```

For each table I would like to remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option on the foreign key constraint named `FK_[TABLENAME]_SerieID`  where `[TABLENAME]` corresponds to the name of the table (and `SerieId` is the same foreign key across tables).

I am able to perform the operation for a particular table, for instance the table called `Table1` using :

```
ALTER TABLE  datasets.Table1
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_SerieID

ALTER TABLE datasets.Table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_SerieID
        FOREIGN KEY (Serie_Id) REFERENCES[dbo].[Serie](SerieID)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
GO
```

I would like to perform the above operation for each table that belong to the schema `datasets` . I'm new to T-SQL and I don't know how to do it.

Should I use a cursor? Can you help me with this?

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not reinvent the wheel. There is excellent script written by **[Aaron Bertrand: Drop and Re-Create All Foreign Key Constraints in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/)**.

You could easily extend it to handle `NO ACTION` case  and specific schema by adding simple `WHERE` restriction:

> ```
> DECLARE @drop   NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
>         @create NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
>
> -- drop is easy,just build a simple concatenated list from sys.foreign_keys:
> SELECT @drop += N'
> ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(cs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ct.name) 
>     + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ';'
> FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
> INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ct
>   ON fk.parent_object_id = ct.[object_id]
> INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS cs 
>   ON ct.[schema_id] = cs.[schema_id]
> WHERE delete_referential_action_desc <> 'NO_ACTION'  -- here 
>     AND cs.name = 'datasets';
>
> -- create is a little more complex. We need to generate the list of 
> -- columns on both sides of the constraint, even though in most cases
> -- there is only one column.
> SELECT @create += N'
> ALTER TABLE ' 
>    + QUOTENAME(cs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ct.name) 
>    + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) 
>    + ' FOREIGN KEY (' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
>    -- get all the columns in the constraint table
>     FROM sys.columns AS c 
>     INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
>     ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
>     AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
>     WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
>     ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
>     FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'')
>   + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(rs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(rt.name)
>   + '(' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
>    -- get all the referenced columns
>     FROM sys.columns AS c 
>     INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
>     ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c.column_id
>     AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c.[object_id]
>     WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
>     ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
>     FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'') + ');'
> FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
> INNER JOIN sys.tables AS rt -- referenced table
>   ON fk.referenced_object_id = rt.[object_id]
> INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS rs 
>   ON rt.[schema_id] = rs.[schema_id]
> INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ct -- constraint table
>   ON fk.parent_object_id = ct.[object_id]
> INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS cs 
>   ON ct.[schema_id] = cs.[schema_id]
> WHERE rt.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND ct.is_ms_shipped = 0
>   AND delete_referential_action_desc <> 'NO_ACTION' -- here
>   AND cs.name = 'datasets';
> print(@drop);
> print(@create);
> -- ...
> ```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca5d60efc6d44b872659117d8b7c9d1a)**

---

One warning! Please avoid adding `ORDER BY`.

This script uses

```
SELECT @drop += N'...'
<=>
SELECT @drop = @drop + N'...'
```

and it may start producing incorrect results. More [nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/5070879)