# SQL Server - aggregate if only one distinct value + nulls without ansi warnings

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-server-2016

Suppose I have a data like this

```
first_name    last_name     city
John          Bon Jovi      null
John          Lennon        null
John          Deer          null
```

And I want to create aggregating query which will return json which looks like this

```
{ "first_name": "John", "city": null }
```

Essentially, the query should check if there's only one distinct value within each column and if it is, put this value to json. All non-null columns are relatively easy to get with a query like this:

```
select
    case when count(distinct first_name) = 1 then max(first_name) end as first_name,
    case when count(distinct last_name) = 1 then max(last_name) end as last_name,
    case when count(distinct city) = 1 then max(city) end as city
from ...
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

or

```
select
    case when max(first_name) = min(first_name) then max(first_name) end as first_name,
    case when max(last_name) = min(last_name) then max(last_name) end as last_name,
    case when max(city) = min(city) then max(city) end as city
from ...
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

The result of the queries above is json like this `{"first_name":"John"}`. But then there are problems with nulls. Problem **(1)** - queries above do not take nulls into account, so if I have data like this

```
first_name    last_name     city
----------------------------------
John          Lennon        null
John          Lennon        null
John          null          null
```

Then last name is also included in the resulting json

```
{ "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Lennon" }
```

Ok, that's understandable (cause `...Null value is eliminated by an aggregate...`) and I can solve it with a query like this:

```
select
    case when count(distinct first_name) = 1 and count(first_name) = count(*) then max(first_name) end as first_name,
    case when count(distinct last_name) = 1 and count(last_name) = count(*) then max(last_name) end as last_name,
    case when count(distinct city) = 1 and count(city) = count(*) then max(city) end as city
from ...
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

But there are other problems with nulls I can't really solve neatly for now. Problem **(2)** - I want to have also `"city":null` in my json. Of course I can do something like this

```
...
case when count(city) = 0 then 'null' end as city
...
```

and then replace string `null` with real nulls, but it's not very neat. Another annoying thing is (**3**) - I'd really like to get rid of warnings

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

without turning `ANSI_WARNINGS` off. For now I can only think about using some placeholders with `isnull` which doesn't look like a clean solution

```
...
case when count(distinct isnull(city, 'null')) = 1 then max(city) end as city
...
```

So, any ideas on how to elegantly solve problems (**2**) and (**3**)? see examples in [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c79f0df2f10a72174865a512197ef1a).

Comment: can you just create a subselect and wrap nullable columns in an isnull?. city = isnull(city,'null')

Comment: So what should happen if the value is *not* distinct? Your question is silent on this, and the answer you posted gives dubious results. To include actual `NULL` s in JSON, use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES`. Avoiding the "null value is eliminated" warning by query trickery is really not worth doing -- the behavior is perfectly deterministic despite it and you only introduce overhead and potential for actual non-determinism by complicating the query. There's a reason it's a *warning* and not an error.

Comment: In case value is not distinct it should not be included in the resulting json. I've had it in a last_name but changed the data a bit to make the case more complicated.
concerning warnings - first, they're annoying. And second, at the moment it breaks our .NET <-> SQL server interaction. I've yet to determine exact minimal example for that, but as long as I have aggregation going over nulls in the trigger my .NET connection fails with "A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active" error.

Comment: and it is really caused by this warning, as long as there're no aggregates over null it doesn't fail.

Comment: Your current answer does not properly take care of non-distinct values in the way you want it, FYI, which is why I asked. Try it with three `John`s and city's `a`, `b` and `c`. The client issue sounds like an annoying bug -- the trigger causes an informational message to be sent, which the client interprets as the availability of a result set/messing with count results. Result sets in triggers are indeed bad in general, but the warning is not, so the check seems overzealous (but I can see how this happens -- distinguishing these cases requires some non-obvious code).

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks for noticing. I have to change an order of variable assignment, I'll change it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so nobody posted any answers so far, I have thought of one way doing it. It's not perfect, but it seems to work.
So the idea is to use `@var = @var + 1` trick inside of select. But it should be a bit more complicated:

```
declare
    @first_name varchar(4), @first_name_state tinyint = 0,
    @last_name varchar(4), @last_name_state tinyint = 0,
    @city varchar(4), @city_state tinyint = 0,
    @country varchar(10), @country_state tinyint = 0,
    @result nvarchar(max) = '{}';

select
    @first_name_state =
        case
            when @first_name_state = 0 then 1
            when @first_name_state = 1 and @first_name = t.first_name then 1
            when @first_name_state = 1 and @first_name is null and t.first_name is null then 1
            else 2
        end,
    @first_name = t.first_name,
    @last_name_state =
        case
            when @last_name_state = 0 then 1
            when @last_name_state = 1 and @last_name = t.last_name then 1
            when @last_name_state = 1 and @last_name is null and t.last_name is null then 1
            else 2
        end,
    @last_name = t.last_name,
    @city_state =
        case
            when @city_state = 0 then 1
            when @city_state = 1 and @city = t.city then 1
            when @city_state = 1 and @city is null and t.city is null then 1
            else 2
        end,
    @city = t.city,
    @country_state =
        case
            when @country_state = 0 then 1
            when @country_state = 1 and @country = t.country then 1
            when @country_state = 1 and @country is null and t.country is null then 1
            else 2
        end,
    @country = t.country
from Table1 as t;

if @first_name_state = 1
    set @result = json_modify(json_modify(@result,'$.first_name','null'),'strict $.first_name',@first_name);

if @last_name_state = 1
    set @result = json_modify(json_modify(@result,'$.last_name','null'),'strict $.last_name',@last_name);

if @city_state = 1
    set @result = json_modify(json_modify(@result,'$.city','null'),'strict $.city',@city);    

if @country_state = 1
    set @result = json_modify(json_modify(@result,'$.country','null'),'strict $.country',@country);    

select @result;
----------------------------------
{"first_name":"John","city":null}
```

see [`db<>fiddle with examples`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad23e898778a080ceb83876934d77cad).

Please note that, according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) you shouldn't use this variable aggregation assignment trick cause some of the statements can be called more than once.

> Don't use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that
>   is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur.
>   Because, all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments)
>   aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row.

I hope in this case it should work fine cause it's not exactly an aggregation, and it's ok if these statements will be called more than once per row.
Still, you can find some useful links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/1744834).