# Order by with variable Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sql command

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',['+ cast(Month as nvarchar(2))+']' , '['+ Cast(Month as nvarchar(2))+']')
FROM    (select distinct Month from Employee  WHERE  Year*100+Month BETWEEN 201704 and 201712 ) as e
PRINT @cols
```

The result was

```
[9],[12],[6],[7],[10],[4],[5],[11],[8]
```

But I really want it to result in sort order

```
[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
```

Comment: Gives an error Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @NassimH What makes you think that would necessarily get different results? Ultimately the final `SELECT` may return results in any order, and may not aggregate properly anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable coalescing [is *documented*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) as being non-deterministic, and [may cause incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/14868997), in particular in the presence of `ORDER BY`. You can also not place `ORDER BY` in a derived table or view, for obvious reasons: the final ordering is determined *only* by the outer query.

You should instead just use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate. You can use `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY` to get the ordering.

Note also:

- Always use `QUOTENAME` to get brackets round your column names, instead of doing it yourself, as escaping can be complex.
- It's better to make exact comparisons on columns, rather than doing calculations on them and then comparing, as then you can hit indexes (sarge-ability).
- It's probably better to store dates in actual date columns, rather than messing around with multiple columns, but I will leave database redesign to you

```sql
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Month), N',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Month)
    FROM (
        select distinct
          Month
        from Employee
        WHERE Year = 2017
          AND Month BETWEEN 4 AND 12
    ) as e
);
```

For SQL Server 2016 and earlier, you can use the old `FOR XML` method:

```sql
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((
    SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(Month)
    FROM (
        select distinct
          Month
        from Employee
        WHERE Year = 2017
          AND Month BETWEEN 4 AND 12
    ) as e
    ORDER BY Month
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  , 1, LEN(N','), N'');
```

Comment: I receive this error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.  I am using sql server 2016

Comment: OK given you a solution for older versions also

Comment: Worked perfectly, I am also using my first comparison (Year*100+month between ...) because some times need more than one year.

Comment: You should still use `AND/OR` logic, eg `WHERE (Year = 2017 AND Month BETWEEN 4 AND 12) OR (Year = 2018 AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 5)`